# Is it possible to run Windows 8 entirely from RAM after boot?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory

How can I extract and run Windows 8 entirely from RAM?

Is it even possible?

Comment: Why, what is your final goal? Also, how much ram do you have to spare that you can dedicate for a ramdisk?

Comment: Just to give you some [minimum numbers](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/system-requirements) you are going to need at ***least*** 17GB (16GB for the ramdisk image and 1 GB for the OS's ram) of RAM on your system to run the 32 bit version. 64 bit will require at least 22GB (20GB + 2GB). Do you have that much ram in your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After boot? Windows standard file caching will gradually pull most of the files you're using (or predicted going to use) to RAM. You can see it yourself when loading some frequently used program without heavy disk activity even though they actually load large data on starting. So go on, jam few gigabytes of RAM in your desktop, and blazing fast system is in your command. On the other hand, there are several product out there that use standard RAM plugged into a device that introduce itself as standard drive. Not only after boot, you're actually booting from a RAM drive. But since you need to provide large enough RAM to run a real server, it would be more cost-effective today to simply buy an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is a program like [Diskless Angel](http://www.disklessangel.com/) that will let you flash memory on boot and then boot directly from RAM.